# Computation in a Quotient Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

I have $f(x)=x^3 +x -2 \in \mathbb{Q[x]}$ and R is the ring $\mathbb{Q[x]}/\langle f \rangle$.

$\alpha = x +\langle f \rangle$ is the image of $x$ in R. Note R is not a field as $f(x)=(x-1)(x^2 +x+2)$.

I need to calculate

$(\alpha ^2 - 2)^2$

and

$(\alpha ^2 - 2)^{-1}$ which is the inverse.

Answers needs to be given in the form of $a\alpha^2 +b\alpha+c$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$.

For the first one, I used the ideal addition and multiplication laws, and reached $(x^4 -4x^2 +4) + \langle f \rangle$ which is basically $(\alpha^2 -2)(\alpha^2 -2)$ but I cannot write it in the form it is asking in terms of $a\alpha^2 +b\alpha+c$. If someone can give me a hint, and just make sure I have got my final calculations correct, and possibly verify the inverse for me as well, I really appreciate their kind favor and time.

Many Thanks

Comment: Hint: by the division algorithm $\, g = qf + r\equiv r\pmod{\!f},\,$ so every poly $\,g\,$ is equal to its remainder $\, r = (g\bmod f)\, $ in $\Bbb Q[x]/(f).\,$ You can compute inverses using the extended Euclidean alhorithm - just as for integers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $x^3+x-2\equiv0\implies x^3\equiv-x+2\implies x^4\equiv-x^2+2x$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for the hint, it made a break through. Now I reached $-5x^2 +2x +4 + \langle f \rangle$ which then I converted to $-5\alpha^2 +2\alpha +4$. Just to be sure I have done it right, is this the right way to convert the ideal back to the requested form?

Comment: That looks right; and now that you can reduce $x^4$ and $x^3$, you can solve $(a\alpha^2+b\alpha+c)(\alpha^2-2)\equiv1$ for $a, b, $ and $c$

Comment: I am stuck at finding the inverse, I am following an example which I cannot understand fully. Can someone help me make a break through?

Answer (score 1):

- $\alpha^3+\alpha-2=0$, so $\alpha^3=-\alpha+2$ and $\alpha^4=-\alpha^2+2\alpha$,

so $\alpha^4-4\alpha^2+4$ simplifies to $-5\alpha^2+2\alpha+4$.

- Now say $(a\alpha^2+b\alpha+c)(\alpha^2-2)=1$.

Thus $a\alpha^4+b\alpha^3+c\alpha^2-2a\alpha^2-2b\alpha-2c=1.$

Thus $a(-2\alpha^2+2\alpha)+b(-\alpha+2)+(c-2a)\alpha^2-2b\alpha-2c=1$.

Thus $(c-3a)\alpha^2+(2a-3b)\alpha+(2b-2c)=1.$

Therefore $c-3a=0, 2a-3b=0$, and $2b-2c=1$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes perfect, the extended euclidean algorithm is hell of time wasting... many thanks